# Unable to track files in long PATHs by Git

Tags: git, addition

Git says to use

```
git add
```

to add untracked files to my repo.

I have run unsuccessfully

```
git add shells/zsh/keyboard_configs/
git add shells/zsh/references/
git add shells/zsh/keyboard_configs/*
git add shells/zsh/references/*

git add shells/zsh/keyboard_configs/*<TAB>
git add shells/zsh/references/*<TAB>
git add .
```

I still get that the files are untracked when I see it at

```
git status
```

**How can you git-add files at long PATHs?**

---

I run

```
$git status                                                                                                                                          ~/bin 
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       shells/zsh/keyboard_configs/
#       shells/zsh/references/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$git add shells/zsh/keyboard_configs                                                                                                                 ~/bin 
$git add shells/zsh/references                                                                                                                       ~/bin
```

The following is what is unexpected. I would expect that I added the folders to be tracked and their contents too.

```
$git status                                                                                                                                          ~/bin 
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       shells/zsh/keyboard_configs/
#       shells/zsh/references/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$
```

Comment: There is no problem with "long paths" in Git. Please show a complete example, starting from an empty repository with "git init", that demonstrates the problem you are seeing. Include both the output of commands and an explanation of what you expect to see.

Comment: I tried what you showed on a new repository and everything worked as expected for me. That is, after running "git add shells/zsh/keyboard_configs/" the file I put in that directory was correctly shown in "git status" as a new file. Again, please show a complete example starting from "git init" to demonstrate your question.

Comment: @Greg: Please, see Tim's answer. He solved the problem with empty .gitignore -files.

Comment: I see. I also tried with an empty directory, thinking that might have been what you were trying to do, but an empty directory did not show up as untracked for me in "git status". Which version of Git are you using?

Comment: I upgraded to 1.6.3.2 thinking that the answer might be something different between my version and yours. I still can't quite reproduce what you saw, but I'm glad you found a solution that works for you.

Comment: @Greg: The same problem occurs for me again. I opened a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084969/unable-to-track-files-in-deep-directories-by-git

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are these directories empty?  If so, Git does not track empty directories.

If you really need to add those directories to your repository, try adding an empty ".gitignore" file in each one.

For some background information on this design decision, see [this thread](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/12/30/4540954) from the Git email list.

Comment: Those directories are not empty. --- Your last tip works. --- Thank you!

Comment: I believe this is also the case if all the files are in .gitignore (Same as empty dir to git)

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the files in those folders are somehow ignored? Check your .gitignore and .git/info/exclude files.

Comment: I have only .DS_Store, MacPorts and .todo in in .git/info/exclude, while I have .gitignore at home and it contains only http://dpaste.com/63048/

Answer (score 0):

If `git config --system core.longpaths true` did not resolve the issue, you should try change the git repos' location as under the "C:/".
(EX: C:/gitRepo)