# How do I remove a submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

How do I remove a Git submodule?
Why can't I do
`git submodule rm module_name`?

Comment: That's actually not true. That answer does not address removing the submodule entry from `.git/config`. The accepted answer shows the up-to-date way to fully remove a a submodule. It's also explained more succinctly in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36593218/1562138

Comment: I found this article very helpful in removing submodules. It includes information on removing entries in the .gitsubmodules and .git/config files [link](https://chrisjean.com/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/)

Comment: Please save yourself some time and directly go the answer that works (in 2017): http://stackoverflow.com/a/36593218/528313

Comment: I've wrestled submodule problems for two days. The breakthrough came when I found this: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13102. Basically, Xcode, and perhaps other apps, struggle to expand url's containing '~'. Once I changed ssh://username@server.remoteHost.com/~/git/MyRepo.git to ssh://username@server.remoteHost.com/home/username/git/MyRepo.git (look up the actual path on your server), all the weirdness disappeared with ten minutes. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833100/adding-a-github-repository-in-xcode-7-using-ssh-authentication-gives-an-authenti/33985629#33985629

Answer (score 2654, accepted):

Since [git1.8.3 (April 22d, 2013)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.8.3-rc0/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.3.txt#L135-L137):

> There was no Porcelain way to say "I no longer am interested in this submodule", once you express your interest in a submodule with "`git submodule init`".
> "**`git submodule deinit`**" is the way to do so.

The deletion process also uses `git rm` (since git1.8.5 October 2013).

### Summary

The 3-steps removal process would then be:

```
0. mv a/submodule a/submodule_tmp

1. git submodule deinit -f -- a/submodule    
2. rm -rf .git/modules/a/submodule
3. git rm -f a/submodule
# Note: a/submodule (no trailing slash)

# or, if you want to leave it in your working tree and have done step 0
3.   git rm --cached a/submodule
3bis mv a/submodule_tmp a/submodule
```

### Explanation

`rm -rf`: This is mentioned in [Daniel Schroeder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2753241/daniel-schroeder)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26505847/6309), and summarized by [Eonil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246776/eonil) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule/16162000?noredirect=1#comment41729982_16162000):

> This leaves `.git/modules/<path-to-submodule>/` unchanged.
> So if you once delete a submodule with this method and re-add them again, it will not be possible because repository already been corrupted.

---

`git rm`: See [commit 95c16418](https://github.com/git/git/commit/95c16418f0375e2fc325f32c3d7578fba9cfd7ef):

> Currently using "`git rm`" on a submodule removes the submodule's work tree from that of the superproject and the gitlink from the index.
> But the submodule's section in `.gitmodules` is left untouched, which is a leftover of the now removed submodule and might irritate users (as opposed to the setting in `.git/config`, this must stay as a reminder that the user showed interest in this submodule so it will be repopulated later when an older commit is checked out).

> Let "`git rm`" help the user by not only removing the submodule from the work tree but by also removing the "`submodule.<submodule name>`" section from the `.gitmodules` file and stage both.

---

`git submodule deinit`: It stems from [this patch](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-v3-submodule-add-deinit-command-td7576946.html):

> With "`git submodule init`" the user is able to tell git they care about one or more submodules and wants to have it populated on the next call to "`git submodule update`".
> But currently there is no easy way they can tell git they do not care about a submodule anymore and wants to get rid of the local work tree (unless the user knows a lot about submodule internals and removes the "`submodule.$name.url`" setting from `.git/config` together with the work tree himself).

> Help those users by providing a '**`deinit`**' command.
> This **removes the whole `submodule.<name>` section from `.git/config` either for the given
> submodule(s)** (or for all those which have been initialized if '`.`' is given).
> Fail if the current work tree contains modifications unless forced.
> Complain when for a submodule given on the command line the url setting can't be found in `.git/config`, but nonetheless don't fail.

This takes care if the (de)initialization steps (`.git/config` and `.git/modules/xxx`)

Since git1.8.5, the `git rm` takes *also* care of the:

- '`add`' step which records the url of a submodule in the `.gitmodules` file: it is need to removed for you.
- the submodule **[special entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992018/git-submodule-update-needed-only-initially/2227598#2227598)** (as illustrated by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16574625/6309)): the git rm removes it from the index:
  `git rm --cached path_to_submodule` (no trailing slash)
  That will remove that directory stored in the index with a special mode "160000", marking it as a submodule root directory.

If you forget that last step, and try to add what was a submodule as a regular directory, you would get error message like:

```
git add mysubmodule/file.txt 
Path 'mysubmodule/file.txt' is in submodule 'mysubmodule'
```

---

Note: since Git 2.17 (Q2 2018), git submodule deinit is no longer a shell script.
It is a call to a C function.

See [commit 2e61273](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e612731b55f1a83fb5b7f4ecb9391f0cba63cb2), [commit 1342476](https://github.com/git/git/commit/13424764db3273091d136bd470cf14852255c98c) (14 Jan 2018) by [Prathamesh Chavan (`pratham-pc`)](https://github.com/pratham-pc).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ead8dbe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ead8dbe2e14ee9a2a18ccd0ad7bca806e1be0d54), 13 Feb 2018)</sup>

```
git ${wt_prefix:+-C "$wt_prefix"} submodule--helper deinit \
  ${GIT_QUIET:+--quiet} \
  ${prefix:+--prefix "$prefix"} \
  ${force:+--force} \
  ${deinit_all:+--all} "$@"
```

Comment: Can you given an example of usage for `submodule deinit`?

Comment: @yourfriendzak here is one example of someone successfully using it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16161950/6309. But keep in mind that, contrary to what I originally believed, 1.8.3 is not yet released! On Unix, you can compile it from the sources.

Comment: In my experience, `git submodule deinit` does not remove the relevant directory from `.git/config`. It's still there until I manually remove it.

Comment: So if I do a pull after someone else has done this, will my submodule be cleaned up for me, or do I still have to do the usual manual steps anyway?  (cf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877420/removing-git-submodules-how-to-automate-removal-on-pull )

Comment: @HamishDowner the special entry should be gone (the directory is no longer a submodule), and the `.gitmodules` should be ok, but I would still double-check anything with the `.git` directory (ie the *local* config, within your local repo: that isn't modified by a `git pull`)

Comment: @VonC I'm still stuck with the .gitmodules file and inside my .git/modules I have a reference as well. Can we just remove these things, ignore them or something third?

Comment: @Warpzit you do have a git1.8.3, and did a `git submodule deinit`? But if not, yes, you can manually clean the extra metadata.

Comment: What do other users who share the git repository need to do?  just `git pull`?

Comment: @Jayen yes, if you commit the removal of the `.gitmodules` entry and the removal of the special entry in the index, and push that repo, others can pull it and that submodule will be gone.

Comment: The `deinit` section of `git-submodule(1)` now recommends using `git rm`: "If you really want to remove a submodule from the repository and commit that use git-rm(1) instead."

Comment: Here's a script that automates those steps: https://gist.github.com/sharplet/6289697. Add it to your `PATH` and `git remove-submodule path/to/submodule`.

Comment: @AdamSharp, wouldn't you need to use `git-remove-submodule ...` instead of `git remove-submodule ....`?

Comment: @kenny no: '`git remove-submodule`' (with a space) will look for an executable '`git-remove-submodule`' (with a dash) anywhere in your `$PATH`.

Comment: I got an error from the script which I think will happen every time: error: submodule 'magit' (or one of its nested submodules) uses a .git directory
(use 'rm -rf' if you really want to remove it including all of its history)
Won't submodules always have a .git directory inside of them?

Comment: @pedz sorry for the late answer. Did you reproduced that error message? Is it in the case of a nested submodule? (a submodule within a submodule)

Comment: @pedz @VonC definitely sounds like it's caused by the nested submodule. Could you try editing the script to run `git rm -rf "$submodule_name"` (note the `-r` flag)? If that works, I'll update the script accordingly.

Comment: @AdamSharp I removed 'magit' which does not have submodules.  Isn't any submodule going to have a .git directory within it?

Comment: @pedz You're right, it doesn't have any submodules. Yes, if a submodule is initialised and checked out, it should have a .git directory. Which version of Git are you using?

Comment: @AdamSharp -- sorry for the slow reply.  I'm not getting the emails.  I don't know which version.  Right now I have 1.8.3.2 and 1.7.12.4.  I upgraded recently.  I had 1.7.4.1 as well.  I don't know which version I used when I did the remove.  Wait - I do recall that 1.7.4 did not have git submodule deinit.

Comment: @pedz yes, `git submodule deinit` is only available from 1.8.3+. Note that, as I mention in my edited answer above, `git rm asubmodule` will soon take care of everything.

Comment: Running the script left me with a broken project. I tried deleting a submodule and then adding it back, with `git submodule add -b master ..`. I got an error, and couldn't add the submodule back anymore:  A git directory for 'asub' is found locally with remote(s):
  origin        url_asub.git
If you want to reuse this local git directory instead of cloning again from
  url_asub.git
use the '--force' option. If the local git directory is not the correct repo
or you are unsure what this means choose another name with the '--name' option.    P.S. This is with git version 1.8.4.msysgit.0

Comment: @TingL You could have converted your existing submodule to make it follow a branch: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309. Or use msysgit 1.8.5.2 (https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=3&q=portable&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount): a `git rm yourSubmodule` now removes the submodule from the working tree and the `.gitmodules` files.

Comment: @TingL I have edited the answer to remove the script, and update the answer to git1.8.5, now available for windows as well with the msysgit 1.8.5.2.

Comment: note: `deinit` and `rm` seem to work with paths, and it worked well for me with a trailing slash on `asubmodule` with both commands. (git v. 1.9.1)

Comment: @desseim yes, and that will be true for all commands: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22130978/6309

Comment: In current git (v1.9+), plain old `git rm submodule` does exactly what you want as other people have already said.

Comment: My experience a good `git rm -rf --cached /path/to/submodule` removes the submodule. Then `git commit`. If I didn't want the folder added as a submodule, I just remove the `.git` in `path/to/folder` and `git add /path/to/folder`.

Comment: This leaves `.git/modules/<path-to-submodule>/` unchanged. So if you once delete a submodule with this method and re-add them again, it will not be possible because repository already been corrupted.

Comment: @VonC Is it really fine to delete such internal structures? Doesn't it affect to any structural data integrity? I'm no expert on Git, but I am losing trust on Git more and more as I getting know about how it fragile is...

Comment: @Eonil no, in this instance, it is ok, in order to keep it coherent with the deletion of the gitlink entry (http://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309).

Comment: "git submodule deinit [submodule]" just gives me a usage prompt - syntax incorrect?

Comment: @NathanHornby it depends on your version of Git (`git --version`). It is for git 1.8.3+. If your version is too old, you should be able to upgrade it easily enough (for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24847953/6309)

Comment: @NathanHornby let me me guess: Ubuntu precise 12.0.4 LTS and Git 1.7.9.5? (http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/vcs/git, and http://stackoverflow.com/q/14409639/6309).

Comment: you better change the order of the commands or you'll get (on Windows) an error for `Stopping at 'lib/asubmodule'; script returned non-zero status.` solution: `git rm lib/asubmodule && rm .git/modules/lib/asubmodule && git submodule lib/asubmodule deinit --recursive --force` (if your module is under root, you don't need lib/)

Comment: @VonC I'm not sure if this Q and the many answers care about history preservation, i.e. vcs time travel, and instead "just want to delete the damn thing". `rm -rf .git/modules/a/submodule` is irreversible unless all commits in the submodule's repo have been pushed to a remote. (If they have been pushed, can I assume checking out a past commit restores it all? I added https://stackoverflow.com/q/61963342/8910547 to represent the alternate scenario. Or perhaps this Q and your answer can be edited to clarify, in which case I might just delete my new Q as redundant.

Comment: rm -rf .git/modules/a/submodule doesn't work for me.  it seems .git is not a directory (but it exists)

Comment: @nurettin true, but in this case, make sure to use without trailing slash, in order to remove the submodule entry, instead of the submodule folder.

Comment: I read your answer a few times, but not sure what you're suggesting to do. Are you suggesting that we just do `git submodule deinit` or follow the steps in the summary? Perhaps you meant to use the word _steps_ instead of _summary_.  Additionally while I understand you'r suggesting two ways to do step `3`. I don't understand what `3bis` is. Would you mind making an edit?

Comment: @mfaani I did not suggested those steps 8 years ago when I wrote this. The answer has been since edited 22 times. But yes, follow the summary steps, and chose between 3 and 3bis, the latter being if you want to keep the content of the former submodule in your working tree.

Answer (score 4663):

In modern git (I'm writing this in 2022, with an updated `git` installation), this has become quite a bit simpler:

- **Run `git rm <path-to-submodule>`, and commit**.

This removes the filetree at `<path-to-submodule>`, and the submodule's entry in the `.gitmodules` file. *I.e.* all traces of the submodule in your repository proper are removed.

As [the docs note](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules#:%7E:text=file%20system%2C%20but-,the%20Git%20directory%20is%20kept%20around,-as%20it%20to) however, the `.git` dir of the submodule is kept around (in the `modules/` directory of the main project's `.git` dir), "**to make it possible to checkout past commits without requiring fetching from another repository**".
If you nonetheless want to remove this info, manually delete the submodule's directory in `.git/modules/`, and remove the submodule's entry in the file `.git/config`. These steps can be automated using the commands

- `rm -rf .git/modules/<path-to-submodule>`, and
- `git config --remove-section submodule.<path-to-submodule>`.

---

Older community wiki instructions:

Via the page *[Git Submodule Tutorial](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial#Removal)*:

**To remove a submodule you need to:**

1. Delete the relevant section from the `.gitmodules` file.
2. Stage the `.gitmodules` changes:
   `git add .gitmodules`
3. Delete the relevant section from `.git/config`.
4. Remove the submodule files from the working tree and index:
   `git rm --cached path_to_submodule` (no trailing slash).
5. Remove the submodule's `.git` directory:
   `rm -rf .git/modules/path_to_submodule`
6. Commit the changes:
   `git commit -m "Removed submodule <name>"`
7. Delete the now untracked submodule files:
   `rm -rf path_to_submodule`

**See also**: [alternative steps below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7646931/5614968).

Comment: "And by the way, is there a reason I can't simply git submodule rm whatever?" ?

Comment: @abernier A curt answer could be "because no such command exists." My guess is that they're trying to make the removal of submodule files vs submodule configuration explicit to avoid accidental data loss. Perhaps one person would think that `git submodule rm` simply removes submodule registration, and would be surprised if the command also deleted the local repository. Any local changes would be irretrievably lost. And perhaps another person would think that only the files would be removed.

Comment: Frankly, I don't know why. I hope they add a command, though. These 4 steps are too complicated.

Comment: i kept on getting this error: "fatal: pathspec 'blocks/submodule_folder/' did not match any files".  i added the -f, --force command: "git rm --cached -f blocks/submodule_folder" and that got rid of the cache.

Comment: @dtan make sure there is no trailing slash

Comment: That didn't work for me. Shouldn't those folders that were previously submodules now appear as ordinary folders within the parent project? Cause they don't for me, and after pushing that change to GitHub it still thinks they're submodules, just that they don't link to the submodule repos anymore...

Comment: okay I had to `git rm --cached -f submodule_name` again, now it works.

Comment: also have to clean .git/modules to allow adding a module later with the same path.

Comment: Here's a bash script that removes a submodule, just create a git alias for submodule-rm ;) https://gist.github.com/2491147

Comment: The submodule directory should be deleted, too, correct? So: `rm -rf path_to_submodule`

Comment: also need rm -rf .git\modules\submodule name?

Comment: Yes, you probably want to delete the now-untracked submodule files.

Comment: You do need to remove the  .git/modules reference directory if you want to re-add the directory as a plain submodule (remembering to delete its internal .git folder as well). See Mark's answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9536504/149416

Comment: You need to stage .gitmodules. Run git add .gitmodules before commiting.

Comment: `git submodule rm` should be a command. This setup becomes way more complicated if you have submodules within submodules because the location of your `.git/config` changes.

Comment: how about delete all cache in a folder like `git rm --cached path_to_sub/*`

Comment: @sidewaysmilk you might just have explained why the command didn't exist.  If you make a command, you should cover all those corner cases, and maybe the decided it would be too hard.

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala Maybe. But it's git! These guys are brilliant. And the most complicated procedure should be the first candidate for automation.

Comment: How does modifying the .git directory by hand work when you push your changes?  Does everyone who uses the master project need to make these changes by hand, and how do they know that they need to make these changes?

Comment: @JamesMoore The modified `.gitmodules` file will be pushed to master, so everyone will see the change. However, the relevant section in `.git/config` will not be pushed to others. It merely a local setting with information about the cloned submodule repo. Other people on your project will still need to delete the submodule repo, if necessary. Git cannot faithfully know if the other people have any unpushed changes in that repo, so it would be unsafe for git to automatically delete their copy.

Comment: The answer is not 100% correct. I found that unless I inserted a "-f" in the "git rm --cached" line, I COULD NOT make this fix work with branches other than "master". Switching to each branch, and using "-f" made it work - I guess it's something to do with the way that editing the config files "breaks" other branches without editing them. Man, submodules are badly designed in git! Never going to use them ever again!

Comment: There 'should' indeed be a command for removing submodules. how about this: git submodule removeUntrackDelete <name> ? Would that suffice for the aforementioned use cases? :) also, with my limited git knowledge, it is easier for me to mess up these 5 (!) steps than to mess up a single step tbh.

Comment: What happens if people have `.git/` with that submodule? Supposing you removed it and push/pull it. There should be a `git submodule rm -f XXX` to avoid data loss.

Comment: If you omit the `--cached` option for step 4 you don't need step 7.

Comment: You should use `git submodule deinit [-f]`

Comment: I had to add a -r to the end of the folder remove to take it out of the index: git rm --cached path_to_submodule -r

Comment: this works for me. I want to change the submodule to real files without any `.gitmodules` track. Then you have to delete every submodule git track and the directory clean, and then rebuild your directory.....why it is so complicated to delete the submodule...

Comment: deinit still leaves content lying around. I wrote a quick script to behave more like OP's commands. https://github.com/mcandre/gus

Comment: rm -rf .git/modules/my_submodule is not a folder.  actually .git is not a directory but a file. Has something changed?

Comment: THIS finally worked. `git rm --cached <subfolder>` did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnDouthat you say "Any local changes would be irretrievably lost" as a reason why it's not automated.  Isn't that risk true for a whole bunch of git commands?  Seems like a normal expectation of cli tools that users ought to read up before hitting enter.

Comment: How do I remove ALL submodules? I've removed them one-by-one via `git rm <path-to-submodule>` but I still have an empty `.gitmodules` file lingering. I want to remove all traces of submodules in my repo.

Comment: I ended up removing the empty `.gitmobules` file and it didn't seem to break anything.

Comment: I have the same issue as Toskan. removing the config section results in `fatal: no such section: submodule.my.submodule`

Comment: If the commands that start with "rm" does not work, start with "git rm ...".

Comment: "In modern git (I'm writing this in 2022, with an updated git installation)" — Could you please say the specific version number you're using. Or even better, the earliest version of git in which it became simpler.

Comment: What does "Stage" mean when saying to stage the changes in step 2?  I haven't heard that term used in git before.  I predominately have been using TortoiseGit context menu for any commits, pushes and pulls.

Comment: What does this sentence mean? "To make it possible to checkout past commits without requiring fetching from another repository". It is not really clear to me

Comment: @Minee that is if you would like to check out earlier commits while that submodule was still in place. If it's cached, the submodule data will be just checked out. If not, Git would have to fetch it again from its remote repo.

Answer (score 938):

The majority of answers to this question are outdated, incomplete, or unnecessarily complex.

A submodule cloned using git 1.7.8 or newer will leave at most four traces of itself in your local repo. The process for removing those four traces is given by the three commands below:

```
# Remove the submodule entry from .git/config
git submodule deinit -f path/to/submodule

# Remove the submodule directory from the superproject's .git/modules directory
rm -rf .git/modules/path/to/submodule

# Remove the entry in .gitmodules and remove the submodule directory located at path/to/submodule
git rm -f path/to/submodule
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not allow for keeping of the files in your working tree (in case you might want to then commit them to your parent repo), nor will `rm -rf` work on Windows.

Comment: the *.gitmodules* file still seems unaffected running these commands

Comment: In 2019 this doesn't work. The last line actually tries to remove from the `.git/modules` folder, which you've already removed in the above line. Adding `--` to the first line like the accepted answer seems to make this work.

Comment: @Fmstrat `git v2.20.1` still left `.git/modules/submodule` at my side in place, so the `rm` seems to be needed now or then.  If newer `git`s want to remove it, fine, **just swap the last two commands**.  Also note that `git deinit` and `git rm` are relatively safe, but **`rm -rf .git/modules/submodule` is dangerous as it might remove the wrong directory**.  You can rename and move submodules around, and they only carry the correct path to remove in the `.git` file (and `.git/config`).  Also removing the module's copy might be wrong in case you jump around in history.  Things are complicated ..

Comment: The second command should remove `.git/modules/name-of-submodule` instead of the path? Though by default, the name Git assigns to the submodule is the path.

Answer (score 631):

Just a note. Since git 1.8.5.2, two commands will do:

```
git rm -r the_submodule
rm -rf .git/modules/the_submodule
```

As @Mark Cheverton's answer correctly pointed out, if the second line isn't used, even if you removed the submodule for now, the remnant .git/modules/the_submodule folder will prevent the same submodule from being added back or replaced in the future. Also, as @VonC mentioned, `git rm` will do most of the job on a submodule.

--Update (07/05/2017)--

Just to clarify, `the_submodule` is the relative path of the submodule inside the project. For example, it's `subdir/my_submodule` if the submodule is inside a subdirectory `subdir`.

As pointed out correctly in the comments and [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44863971/683218), the two commands (although functionally sufficient to remove a submodule), do leave a trace in the `[submodule "the_submodule"]` section of `.git/config` (as of July 2017), which can be removed using a third command:

```
git config -f .git/config --remove-section submodule.the_submodule 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: I'm on git version 2.4.9 (Apple Git-60) and all I had to do was rm the_submodule. I pushed that then re-added a folder named the same as the submodule and it worked without issue.

Comment: I'm on git version 2.5.4 on OSX and you only need to do the second command if you want to re-add the submodule from another location. If you don't do the second step you'll see this:  A git directory for 'submodule' is found locally with remote(s):

Comment: This does not remove the submodule entry from `.git/config`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36593218/1562138 for the complete way to remove a submodule.

Comment: @fvgs with git 2.7.4 the `git rm` command DOES remove the section from .git/config, as well as removing the .git/modules/... folder(s)

Comment: @drevicko I just tested this with Git 2.11.1 and I observe the same behavior as before. `git init && git submodule add <repository> && git rm <name>` leaves behind the `.git/config` entry and the `.git/modules/<name>` directory and its contents. Perhaps you didn't initialize the submodule prior to removing it?

Comment: @fvgs ok, I get the same here with git 2.7.4 when I try your experiment - not sure what happened? The submodule was definitely initialised, had been around a while with multiple changes.

Comment: i feel safer running this first .. git submodule deinit -f the_submodule

Comment: Can the answer clarify what `the_submodule` is here? The path to the submodule?

Comment: It's worth noting that if you never had that submodule initialized in the repository you run these commands on (e.g. you created a fresh, non-recursive clone) you don't need to run the second command or remove the section from the git config, as those elements won't exist.

Comment: @danday74 your command is actually needed if the submodule is checked out. otherwise you will get an error `Unlink of file '...' failed`

Comment: This seemed to work in 2020, and is possibly the most simple, except it does not seem to remove the actual code. which would need
`git rm -f path/to/submodule`
I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/36593218/2808203 is the better solution.

Comment: hmm... on git 1.8.3.1 I do not have `.git/modules/`

Answer (score 238):

**Simple steps**

1. Remove config entries:
   `git config -f .git/config --remove-section submodule.$submodulename`
    `git config -f .gitmodules --remove-section submodule.$submodulename`
2. Remove directory from index:
   `git rm --cached $submodulepath`
3. Commit
4. Delete unused files:
   `rm -rf $submodulepath`
   `rm -rf .git/modules/$submodulename`

*Please note:* `$submodulepath` doesn't contain leading or trailing slashes.

**Background**

When you do `git submodule add`, it only adds it to `.gitmodules`, but
once you did `git submodule init`, it added to `.git/config`.

So if you wish to remove the modules, but be able to restore it quickly,
then do just this:

```
git rm --cached $submodulepath
git config -f .git/config --remove-section submodule.$submodulepath
```

It is a good idea to do `git rebase HEAD` first and `git commit`
at the end, if you put this in a script.

Also have a look at [an answer to *Can I unpopulate a Git submodule?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5387510/319266).

Comment: I had a lot of submodules (and a bigger mess) so I had to pass them through a for loop. Since most of them where under a specific directory and ls output contained trailing slashes. I did something like `for dir in directory/*; do git rm --cached $dir; done`.

Comment: To get this the list which can be used in script for recursive deletion - `git config -f .git/config -l | cut -d'=' -f1 | grep "submodule.$MODPATH" | sed 's/^submodule\.//' | sed 's/\.url$//'` - - looks like you have to really do this in case if there is something messed up, otherwise just `git submodule | grep -v '^+' | cut -d' ' -f3`

Comment: to get the list of modules where no local changes had been made - `git submodule | grep '^+' | cut -d' ' -f2`

Comment: note, I had to include `submodulename` in double quotes `"submodulename"` .. referring the `.git/config` file

Comment: Simple. Efficient. In 2.25.0, after the step 1, you need to stage .gitmodules changes before step 2.

Answer (score 117):

To remove a submodule added using:

```sh
REPOSITORY=blah@blah.com:repos/blah.git
MOD_DIR=lib/blah
git submodule add $REPOSITORY $MOD_DIR
```

Run:

```sh
git rm $MOD_DIR
```

That's it.

For old versions of git (circa ~1.8.5, actually even in 2.26.2) use:

```sh
git submodule deinit $MOD_DIR
git rm $MOD_DIR
git config -f .gitmodules --remove-section submodule.$MOD_DIR
```

Comment: `git rm` still leaves stuff in `.git/modules/`. (2.5.4)

Comment: @RudolfAdamkovic it works for me? Notice it only removes the submodule entry if the exact path matches; if you've moved a submodule and then use `git rm` it doesn't; A quick test with 2.5.4 on my mac updates the .gitmodules file, as described in the documentation here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm#_submodules ... but if you have found some kind of combination of platform / version where this doesn't happen, you should probably lodge a bug about it.

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct. `git rm` leaves stuff in `.git/modules/` dir and  `.git/config` file (ubuntu, git 2.7.4). Other answer works 100%: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36593218/4973698

Comment: Will deinit remove the submodule but leave the files? I want it to remove all of the remnants in git but leave the actual folder in place.

Comment: @justin.m.chase It looks like git rm --cached $MOD_DIR will leave the files in place but you'll have to manually remove the .gitmodules entry.

Comment: Doesn't work. Accidentally typed the wrong URL and I can't get rid of it any more. `git submodule delete --force` desperately needed.

Answer (score 86):

In addition to the recommendations, I also had to `rm -Rf .git/modules/path/to/submodule` to be able to add a new submodule with the same name (in my case I was replacing a fork with the original)

Comment: I was having troubles with this as well. If you try to reinstall a submodule to the same path, it keeps the branch info cached in the location you mentioned which messes things up.

Comment: Thanks, I needed this too. @Anton, I agree, and I've edited the topvoted answer to add this info.

Comment: I used the --name option to make the replace work... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404704/how-do-i-replace-a-git-submodule-with-another-repo

Answer (score 69):

You must remove the entry in `.gitmodules` and `.git/config`, and remove the directory of the module from the history:

```
git rm --cached path/to/submodule
```

If you'll write on git's mailing list probably someone will do a shell script for you.

Comment: There is no need for any shell script, other answer has commands for removing all traces of a submodule: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36593218/4973698

Answer (score 48):

I found `deinit` works good for me:

```
git submodule deinit <submodule-name>    
git rm <submodule-name>
```

From [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#git-submodule-deinit):

> **deinit**
>
> Unregister the given submodules, i.e. remove the whole `submodule.$name`
> section from .git/config together with their work tree.

Comment: Agree found same solution. It's a best way today in 2018 )

Comment: it did not remove .git/modules/.. . You should remove them, see the answer by @fvgs

Comment: Don't know why this simple and easy solution isn't number 1

Comment: AFAICS this seems to be the **most safest answer for newer `git`s** which know of `deinit`, as [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36593218/490291) removes the `.git/modules/submodule` directory too early, which seems to make newer `git`s to fail now or then.  Also (see my comment there) removing `.git/modules/submodule` might be the wrong path, so this is a dangerous step, best taken later only when `git` complains (or if you are 299% sure this what you want, is the correct path and really needed).

Comment: I also needed `git commit` to commit staged changes in working dir: `modified .gitmodules` and `deleted <submodule-path>`.

Comment: As of git 2.31.0, if you later add another submodule at same path, git will happily not update .git/modules/submodule/config with the new submodule's repository path (nor warn) so a future git push/pull will not work.  That's when you need to remove .git/modules/submodule before doing the add again.

Comment: Can we admit Git's submodules are way too complicated?

Answer (score 46):

You can use an alias to automate the solutions provided by others:

```
[alias]
  rms = "!f(){ git rm --cached \"$1\";rm -r \"$1\";git config -f .gitmodules --remove-section \"submodule.$1\";git config -f .git/config --remove-section \"submodule.$1\";git add .gitmodules; }; f"
```

Put that in your git config, and then you can do: `git rms path/to/submodule`

Comment: -1 as this is plain too wrong.  FIRST:  This assumes that the submodule's name and path are identical **which is most often not the case**.  I.E. `git clone https://github.com/hilbix/empty.git; cd empty; git submodule add https://github.com/hilbix/empty.git one; git mv one two; git rms two`.  SECOND: 
 You must execute this from the correct path.  `git` aliases should work anywhere in the worktree (or fail gracefully).  THIRD: `git config -f .git/config` fails within submodules, as `.git` usually is a file there.

Answer (score 45):

To summarize, this is what you should do :

1. Set `path_to_submodule` var (no trailing slash):

   `path_to_submodule=path/to/submodule`
2. Delete the relevant line from the .gitmodules file:

   `git config -f .gitmodules --remove-section submodule.$path_to_submodule`
3. Delete the relevant section from .git/config

   `git config -f .git/config --remove-section submodule.$path_to_submodule`
4. Unstage and remove $path_to_submodule only from the index (to prevent losing information)

   `git rm --cached $path_to_submodule`
5. Track changes made to .gitmodules

   `git add .gitmodules`
6. Commit the superproject

   `git commit -m "Remove submodule submodule_name"`
7. Delete the now untracked submodule files

   `rm -rf $path_to_submodule`

   `rm -rf .git/modules/$path_to_submodule`

Comment: so everyone else who pulls down my change will have to run rm -rf $path_to_submodule

rm -rf .git/modules/$path_to_submodule to remove the submodule cache ?

Comment: I recommend to update, `git submodule update`. And if the submodules paths weren't updated correctly (git throws an error), remove them:
`rm -rf .git/modules/<submodule> && rm -rf <submodule> && git submodule update`

Answer (score 44):

If the submodule was *accidentally* added because you added, committed and pushed a folder that was already a Git repository (contained `.git`), you won’t have a `.gitmodules` file to edit, or anything in `.git/config`. [In this case all you need](http://humansky.com/2011/12/accidentally-adding-a-git-submodule/) is :

```
git rm --cached subfolder
git add subfolder
git commit -m "Enter message here"
git push
```

[FWIW](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/FWIW), I also removed the `.git` folder before doing the `git add`.

Comment: exactly my case

Answer (score 32):

1. `git submodule deinit <path to submodule>`
2. Remove the section from `.gitmodules`
3. `git rm <path to submodule>`
4. Delete the module files which you need to remove from your project.
5. Add the deleted files to git and call `git add .gitmodules`
6. Commit and Push

Comment: For me it was enough to call `git submodule deinit <submodule_name>` and `git rm <path_to_submodule>`. Last command automatically deletes the entry inside the `.gitmodules`. Git 2.17

Comment: I needed `-r` with `git rm`: `git rm -r <path_to_submodule>`

Answer (score 25):

After experimenting with all the different answers on this site, I ended up with this solution:

```
#!/bin/sh
path="$1"
if [ ! -f "$path/.git" ]; then
  echo "$path is no valid git submodule"
  exit 1
fi
git submodule deinit -f $path &&
git rm --cached $path &&
rm -rf .git/modules/$path &&
rm -rf $path &&
git reset HEAD .gitmodules &&
git config -f .gitmodules --remove-section submodule.$path
```

This restores the exact same state as before you added the submodule. You can right away add the submodule again, which was not possible with most of the answers here.

```
git submodule add $giturl test
aboveScript test
```

This leaves you with a clean checkout with no changes to commit.

This was tested with:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)
```

Comment: Why do you use `git rm --cached $path` then `rm -rf $path` instead of `git rm -r $path`?

Comment: -1 Does not work if you try to remove a submodule within a submodule (submodule can form trees!).  Also **this is dangerously buggy** due to missing quoting!  Example `git submodule add https://github.com/hilbix/empty.git 'dangerous .. submodule'` -> when you try to remove 'dangerous .. submodule' with your script, this will `rm -rf ..` which is most likely not what you want ..

Answer (score 20):

What I'm currently doing Dec 2012 (combines most of these answers):

```
oldPath="vendor/example"
git config -f .git/config --remove-section "submodule.${oldPath}"
git config -f .gitmodules --remove-section "submodule.${oldPath}"
git rm --cached "${oldPath}"
rm -rf "${oldPath}"              ## remove src (optional)
rm -rf ".git/modules/${oldPath}" ## cleanup gitdir (optional housekeeping)
git add .gitmodules
git commit -m "Removed ${oldPath}"
```

Answer (score 16):

I recently find out a git project which include many useful git related command: https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras

Install it and type :

```
git-delete-submodule submodule
```

Then things are done. The submodule directory will be removed from your repo and still exist in your filesystem. You can then commit the change like: `git commit -am "Remove the submodule"`.

Comment: You can call this as `git delete-submodule`, as `git-extras` needs to be in the path to work.  Also note that **I recommend to not use `git-extras`**, as many parts of it are **extremely buggy and dangerous**.  I.E. `git-delete-submodule` possibly removes the wrong path below `.git/modules/*`, as it assumes that the module and the path are identical (which is quite often not the case), and it does not work correctly if you try to remove a submodule within a submodule.  `git-extras` might be 99% helpful, but please do not complain if things utterly go wrong using it.  **YOU HAVE BEEN WARNED!**

Comment: For saving time use this commands `apt install git-extras && git delete-submodule submodule`. @Chien-Wei Huang has extra `-` in post

Answer (score 16):

Here is what I did :

1.) Delete the relevant section from the .gitmodules file. You can use below command:

```
git config -f .gitmodules --remove-section "submodule.submodule_name"
```

2.) Stage the `.gitmodules` changes

```
git add .gitmodules
```

3.) Delete the relevant section from `.git/config`. You can use below command:

```
git submodule deinit -f "submodule_name"
```

4.) Remove the gitlink (no trailing slash):

```
git rm --cached path_to_submodule
```

5.) Cleanup the `.git/modules`:

```
rm -rf .git/modules/path_to_submodule
```

6.) Commit:

```
git commit -m "Removed submodule <name>"
```

7.) Delete the now untracked submodule files

```
rm -rf path_to_submodule
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  For me, I had to rearrange the first three steps' order to 3), 1), 2). Doing 1) first gave `fatal: no submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'submodule_name'` at step 3.  Both steps were necessary though.  (git v2.8.2)

Answer (score 16):

All the answers look outdated. I am using git version `2.28.0`. One line answer is,

```sh
git rm path-to-submodule
```

However, even though the submodule is removed from source control, .git/modules/path-to-submodule still contains the submodule repository and .git/config contains its URL, so you still have to remove those manually:

```sh
git config --remove-section submodule.path-to-submodule
rm -rf .git/modules/path-to-submodule
```

Sometimes, you have to use the `-f` flag:

```
$ git rm -f img2vec
```

For example, because you might get an error like this:

```
$ git rm img2vec/
error: the following file has changes staged in the index:
    img2vec
(use --cached to keep the file, or -f to force removal)
```

Comment: Outdated? [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309) does mention the `git rm` option and the associated config change.

Comment: Since this the top & most recent answer, you should update it with the following steps as well:

1. Remove the `.gitmodules` file.
2. Remove relevant data from the index as well by invoking the `git rm --cached -r <path-to-submodule-dir>`

Answer (score 15):

For the benefit of the reader, this here tries to sum it up and give a step-by-step guide on how to do it if things do not work as expected.  Following is the **tested and safe way** for `git` version `2.17` and above **to get rid of a submodule**:

```
submodule="path/to/sub"              # no trailing slash!
git submodule deinit -- "$submodule"
git rm -- "$submodule"
```

- If this does not work for you, see below.
- No options.  Nothing dangerous.  And do not even consider doing more!
- Tested with Debian Buster `2.20.1` and Ubuntu 18.04 `2.17.1`.
- `"$submodule"` is just to emphasize where to put the name, and that you have to be careful with spaces and the like
- If on Windows ignore the first line and replace `"$submodule"` with the Windows way of a properly specified path to the submodule.  (I am not Windows)

> Warning!
>
> **Never touch the insides of the `.git` directory yourself!**  Editing inside `.git` enters the dark side.  Stay away at all cost!
>
> And yes, you can blame `git` for this, as many handy things were missing in `git` in the past.  Like a proper way to remove submodules again.
>
> I think there is a very dangerous part in the documentation of `git submodule`.
>   It recommends to remove `$GIT_DIR/modules/<name>/` yourself.
>   **In my understanding this is not only plain wrong, it is extremely dangerous and provokes major headaches in future!**  See below.

Note that

```
git module deinit
```

is the direct inverse to

```
git module init
```

but

```
git submodule deinit -- module
git rm -- module
```

also is quite the inverse to

```
git submodule add -- URL module
git submodule update --init --recursive -- module
```

because some commands basically need to do more than just a single thing:

- `git submodule deinit -- module`

  - (1) updates `.git/config`
- `git rm`

  - (2) removes the files of the module
  - (3) thereby recursively removes the submodules of the submodule
  - (4) updates `.gitmodules`
- `git submodule add`

  - pulls in the data to `.git/modules/NAME/`
  - (1) does `git submodule init`, so updates `.git/config`
  - (2) does `git submodule update`, so, nonrecursively checks out the module
  - (4) updates `.gitmodules`
- `git submodule update --init --recursive -- module`

  - pulls in further data if needed
  - (3) checks out the submodules of the submodule recursively

This cannot be fully symmetric, as keeping it strictly symmetric does not make much sense.  There simply is no need for more than two commands.  Also "pulling in the data" is implicit, because you need it, but removing the cached information is not done, because this is not needed at all and might wipe precious data.

This truly is puzzling to newcomers, but basically is a good thing:  `git` just does the obviously thing and does that right, and does not even try to do more.  `git` is a tool, which must do a reliable job, instead of being just another "Eierlegende Wollmilchsau" ("Eierlegende Wollmilchsau" translates for me to "some evil version of a Swiss army knife").

So I understand complaints of people, saying "Why doesn't do `git` the obvious thing for me".  This is because "obvious" here depends from the point of view.  Reliability in each and every situation is far more important.  Hence what's obvious for you often is not the right thing in all possible technical situations.  Please remember that:  AFAICS `git` follows the technical path, not the social one.  (Hence the clever name: git)

### If this fails

The commands above may fail due to following:

- Your `git` is too old.  Then use a newer `git`.  (See below how to.)
- You have uncommitted data and might lose data.  Then better commit them first.
- Your submodule is not clean in a `git clean` sense.  Then first clean your submodule using that command.  (See below.)
- You have done something in the past which is unsupported by `git`.  Then you are on the dark side and things get ugly and complicated.  (Perhaps using another machine fixes it.)
- Perhaps there are more ways to fail I am not aware of (I am just some `git` power-user.)

Possible fixes follow.

#### Use a newer `git`

If your machine is too old there is no `submodule deinit` in your `git`.  If you do not want (or can) update your `git`, then just use another machine with a newer `git`!  `git` is meant to be fully distributed, so you can use another `git` to get the job done:

- `workhorse:~/path/to/worktree$ git status --porcelain` **must not** output anything!  If it does, cleanup things first!
- `workhorse:~/path/to/worktree$ ssh account@othermachine`
- `othermachine:~$ git clone --recursive me@workhorse path/to/worktree/.git TMPWORK && cd TMPWORK`
- Now do the submodule stuff
- `othermachine:~/TMPWORK$ git commit . -m . && exit`
- `workhorse:~/path/to/worktree$ git fetch account@othermachine:TMPWORK/.git`
- `workhorse:~/path/to/worktree$ git merge --ff-only FETCH_HEAD`.  If this does not work, use `git reset --soft FETCH_HEAD`
- Now cleanup things, until `git status` is clean again.  You are able to do so, because you have had it clean before, thanks to the first step.

This `othermachine` can be some VM, or some Ubuntu WSL under Windows, whatever.  Even a `chroot` (but I assume that you are non-root, because if you are `root` it should be more easy to update to the newer `git`).

Note that if you cannot `ssh` in, there are trainloads of ways to transport `git` repositories.  You can copy your worktree on some USB stick (including the `.git` directory), and clone from the stick.  Clone the copy, just to get things in a clean fashion again.  This might be a PITA, in case your submodules are not accessible from othermachine directly.  But there is a solution for this, too:

```
git config --add url.NEWURLPREFIX.insteadOf ORIGINALURLPREFIX
```

You can use this multiply, and this is saved into `$HOME/.gitconfig`.  Something like

```
git config --add 'url./mnt/usb/repo/.insteadof' https://github.com/
```

rewrites URLs like

```
https://github.com/XXX/YYY.git
```

into

```
/mnt/usb/repo/XXX/YYY.git
```

It's easy if you start to become accustomed to powerful `git` features like this.

#### Cleanup things first

Cleaning manually up is good, because this way you perhaps detect some things you forgot about.

- If git complains about unsaved stuff, commit and push it somewhere safe.
- If git complains about some leftovers, `git status` and `git clean -ixfd` is your friend
- Try to abstain from options to `rm` and `deinit` as long as you can.  Options (like `-f`) for `git` are good if you are a Pro.  But as you came here, you probably are not so experienced in the `submodule` area.  So better be safe than sorry.

Example:

```
$ git status --porcelain
 M two
$ git submodule deinit two
error: the following file has local modifications:
    two
(use --cached to keep the file, or -f to force removal)
fatal: Submodule work tree 'two' contains local modifications; use '-f' to discard them
$ cd two
$ git submodule deinit --all
error: the following file has local modifications:
    md5chk
(use --cached to keep the file, or -f to force removal)
fatal: Submodule work tree 'md5chk' contains local modifications; use '-f' to discard them
$ cd md5chk
$ git submodule deinit --all
error: the following file has local modifications:
    tino
(use --cached to keep the file, or -f to force removal)
fatal: Submodule work tree 'tino' contains local modifications; use '-f' to discard them
$ cd tino
$ git status --porcelain
?? NEW
$ git clean -i -f -d
Would remove the following item:
  NEW
*** Commands ***
    1: clean                2: filter by pattern    3: select by numbers    4: ask each
    5: quit                 6: help
What now> 1
Removing NEW
$ cd ../../..
$ git status --porcelain
$ git submodule deinit two
Cleared directory 'two'
Submodule 'someunusedname' (https://github.com/hilbix/src.git) unregistered for path 'two'
```

You see, there is no `-f` needed on `submodule deinit`.  If things are clean, in a `git clean` sense.  Also note that `git clean -x` is not needed.  **This means `git submodule deinit` unconditionally removes untracked files which are ignored.**  This is usually what you want, but do not forget about it.  Sometimes ignored files might be precious, like cached data which takes hours to days to be calculated again.

### Why never remove `$GIT_DIR/modules/<name>/`?

Probably people want to remove the cached repository, because they are afraid to run into a problem later.  This is true, but running into that "problem" is the correct way to solve it!  Because the fix is easy, and done right you will be able to live happily ever after.  This avoids more cumbersome trouble than when you remove the data yourself.

Example:

```
mkdir tmptest &&
cd tmptest &&
git init &&
git submodule add https://github.com/hilbix/empty.git two &&
git commit -m . &&
git submodule deinit two &&
git rm two &&
git commit -m . &&
git submodule add https://github.com/hilbix/src.git two
```

The last line outputs following error:

```
A git directory for 'two' is found locally with remote(s):
  origin    https://github.com/hilbix/empty.git
If you want to reuse this local git directory instead of cloning again from
  https://github.com/hilbix/src.git
use the '--force' option. If the local git directory is not the correct repo
or you are unsure what this means choose another name with the '--name' option.
```

Why this error?  Because `.git/modules/two/` previously was populated from https://github.com/hilbix/empty.git and now shall be re-populated from something else, namely https://github.com/hilbix/src.git.  You won't see this if you re-populate it from https://github.com/hilbix/empty.git

What to do now?  Well, just do exactly as told!  Use `--name someunusedname`

```
git submodule add --name someunusedname https://github.com/hilbix/src.git two
```

`.gitmodules` then looks like

```
[submodule "someunusedname"]
    path = two
    url = https://github.com/hilbix/src.git
```

`ls -1p .git/modules/` gives

```
someunusedname/
two/
```

This way **in future you can switch branches/commit forward and backward and will never get into any trouble again**, due to `two/` having two different (and possibly incompatible) upstream repositories.  And the best is:  You keep both cached locally, too.

- This is not only true for you.  It also is true for all others using your repository.
- And you do not lose history.  In case you forgot to push the very latest version of the old submodule, you can enter the local copy and do so later on.  Note that it is quite common that somebody forgets to push some submodules (because this is a PITA for newcomers, until they became accustomed to `git`).

However if you removed the cached directory, both different checkouts will stumble upon each other, because you will not use the `--name` options, right?  So each time you do the checkout you perhaps have to remove the `.git/modules/<module>/` directory again and again.  This is extremely cumbersome and makes it hard to use something like `git bisect`.

So there is a very technical reason to keep this module directory as a placeholder.  People who recommend to remove something below `.git/modules/` either do not know better or forget to tell you that this makes powerful features like `git bisect` nearly impossible to use if this crosses such a submodule incompatibility.

A further reason is shown above.  Look at the `ls`.  What do you see there?

Well, the 2nd variant of module `two/` is not under `.git/modules/two/`, it is under `.git/modules/someunusedname/`!  So things like `git rm $module; rm -f .git/module/$module` are totally wrong!  You must either consult `module/.git` or `.gitmodules` to find the right thing to remove!

So not only most other answers fall into this dangerous trap, [even very popular `git` extensions had this bug](https://github.com/tj/git-extras/issues/799) ([it's now fixed there](https://github.com/tj/git-extras/pull/801))!  So better keep your hands of the `.git/` directory if you do not exactly, what you are doing!

> And from the philosophical view, wiping history is always wrong!
>   [Except for quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_eraser_experiment), as usual, but this is something completely different.

FYI you probably guessed it: [hilbix](https://github.com/hilbix/) is my GitHub account.

Comment: This encyclopedia of a post should be broken up into clearer sections with bigger/clearer sub headings to indicate the actual answer, and the different "troubleshooting"/etc sections.

Comment: agree with 'never remove $GIT_DIR/modules/<name>/'

Comment: Great answer with gotchas I am certain to have learned about the hard way. Highly recommend everyone at least speed reads it.

Answer (score 12):

I had to take John Douthat's steps one step further and `cd` into the submodule's directory, and then remove the Git repository:

```
cd submodule
rm -fr .git
```

Then I could commit the files as a part of the parent Git repository without the old reference to a submodule.

Comment: I had to do this too in order to get past a "fatal: Not a git repository:" error when trying to do the `git rm --cache` step.

Answer (score 12):

With git v2.7.4 simple 3 steps worked just fine.

```
git submodule deinit -f -- a/submodule    
git rm -f a/submodule
git commit
```

Comment: git version 2.39.2 but this worked, no need to force btw, thx

Answer (score 11):

Here are the 4 steps that I found necessary or useful (important ones first):

```
git rm -f the_submodule
rm -rf .git/modules/the_submodule
git config -f .git/config --remove-section submodule.the_submodule
git commit -m "..."
```

**In theory**, `git rm` in *step 1* should take care of it. Hopefully, the second part of OP question can be answered positively one day (that this can be done in one command).

But as of July 2017, *step 2* is necessary to remove data in `.git/modules/` for otherwise, you can't e.g. add the submodule back in the future.

You can probably get away with the above two steps for git 1.8.5+ as [tinlyx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21211232/3363202) noted, as all `git submodule` commands seem to work.

Step 3 removes the section for `the_submodule` in the file `.git/config`. This should be done for completeness. (The entry may cause problems for older git versions, but I don't have one to test).

For this, most answers suggest using `git submodule deinit`. I find it more explicit and less confusing to use `git config -f .git/config --remove-section`. According to the [git-submodule documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), `git deinit`:

> Unregister the given submodules ... If you really want to remove a
>   submodule from the repository and commit that use git-rm[1]
>   **instead**.

Last but not least, if you don't  `git commit`, you will/may get an error when doing `git submodule summary` (as of git 2.7):

```
fatal: Not a git repository: 'the_submodule/.git'
* the_submodule 73f0d1d...0000000:
```

This is regardless of whether you do steps 2 or 3.

Answer (score 11):

## The best way to remove a submodule from git:

```
$ git submodule deinit -f <submodule-name>
$ rm -rf .git/modules/<submodule-name>
$ git config -f .gitmodules --remove-section submodule.<submodule-name>
$ git config -f .git/config --remove-section submodule.<submodule-name>
$ git rm --cached <submodule-name>
$ git commit -m 'rm submodule: <submodule-name>'
```

Comment: Question: Isn't this missing a `git add .gitmodules`?

Comment: yes you can add this, `git add .gitmodules`

Answer (score 9):

I just found the `.gitmodules` hidden file, it has a list... you can erase them individually that way. I just had one, so I deleted it. Simple, but it might mess up Git, since I don't know if anything's attached to the submodule. Seems ok so far, aside from libetpan's usual upgrade issue, but that's (hopefully) unrelated.

Answer (score 9):

I followed the instructions from this very same guide
[How do I remove a submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70530218/6014368)

```
$ git submodule deinit -f <submodule-name>
$ rm -rf .git/modules/<submodule-name>
$ git config -f .gitmodules --remove-section submodule.<submodule-name>
$ git config -f .git/config --remove-section submodule.<submodule-name>
$ git rm --cached <submodule-name>
$ git commit -m 'rm submodule: <submodule-name>'
```

But it kept saying:

```
fatal: no submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path
```

So what I did is including the path in .gitignore like this (With no asterisk in the end of the path):

```
<path>
```

Then I modified any file and did a **simple push**:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Ignoring sharedlibs folder <path> on .gitignore"
$ git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 8):

With git 2.17 and above it's just:

```
git submodule deinit -f {module_name}
git add {module_name}
git commit
```

Comment: Did not work, neither for `git 2.17.1` nor `git 2.20.1`.  However using `git rm` instead of `git add` worked for both.  Notes: **`-f` is not needed** if things are clean.  Be sure to **never use options** with `git` if you want to protect against unintended data loss.  Also note that this leaves `.git/modules/{module_name}` in place.  **It is best practice to keep it there** because `git` prints the correct(!) help how to proceed if something is blocked due to this.

Answer (score 7):

```
project dir:     ~/foo_project/
submodule:       ~/foo_project/lib/asubmodule
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
run:
  1.   cd ~/foo_project
  2.   git rm lib/asubmodule && 
          rm .git/modules/lib/asubmodule && 
            git submodule lib/asubmodule deinit --recursive --force
```

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion you can do this with below three steps

This command will delete content

```
git submodule deinit -f devops
```

Now remove the directory

```
rm -rvf devops
```

The last step is to remove entry from submodule file

```
git rm -f devops
```

This is not it delete module directory from .git hierarchy

```
cd .git/modules/ && rm -rvf devops
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have just added the submodule, and for example, you simply added the wrong submodule or you added it to the wrong place, simply do `git stash` then delete the folder. This is assuming that adding the submodule is the only thing you did in the recent repo.

Answer (score 5):

**To summarize, this is what you should do :**

Set path_to_submodule var (no trailing slash):

```
path_to_submodule=path/to/submodule
```

Delete the relevant line from the .gitmodules file:

```
git config -f .gitmodules --remove-section submodule.$path_to_submodule
```

Delete the relevant section from .git/config

```
git config -f .git/config --remove-section submodule.$path_to_submodule
```

Unstage and remove $path_to_submodule only from the index (to prevent losing information)

```
git rm --cached $path_to_submodule
```

Track changes made to .gitmodules

```
git add .gitmodules
```

Commit the superproject

```
git commit -m "Remove submodule submodule_name"
```

Delete the now untracked submodule files

```
rm -rf $path_to_submodule

rm -rf .git/modules/$path_to_submodule
```

See also : [Alternative guide lines](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial#Removal)

Comment: Can you please extend this with how to remove a submodule following a 'git submodule add' but without having ever committed it? I assume that in that case no commit is needed to remove the submodule, right?

Comment: I think you need to swap the `git rm --cached $path_to_submodule` and `git add .gitmodules` no? I did get an error on the first command: `fatal: Please stage your changes to .gitmodules or stash them to proceed` because I had unstaged changes to `.gitmodules`. Doing the `git add .gitmodules` first solves that.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me. The above answers were showing this in the terminal and nothing else was happening

```
'fatal: not removing 'demolibapp' recursively without -r'
```

1. **demolibapp** is my submodule name that I want to remove
2. git submodule deinit demolibapp
3. git rm --cached demolibapp -r
4. rm -rf .git/modules/demolibapp
5. git add --all
6. git commit -m "removing extra submodules"
7. git push
8. rm -rf demolibapp

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove the submodule without deleting the folder from your local file system here is what worked for me:

```sh
MOD=example
git rm --cached -f apps/$MOD
git config -f .gitmodules --remove-section submodule.$MOD
```

Answer (score 2):

I've created a bash script to ease the removal process. It also checks whether there are changes in the repo left unsaved and asks for confirmation. 
It has been tested on `os x` would be interesting to know if it works as is on common linux distros as well:

https://gist.github.com/fabifrank/cdc7e67fd194333760b060835ac0172f

Answer (score 2):

## A simple solution using Magit

If you use [Magit](https://magit.vc/) under Emacs you can proceed as follows:

Go to your project root, then

`M-x`, `magit-list-submodules`

then

`M-x`, `magit-submodule-remove`

You will be asked which submodule you want to remove.

That's it!

---

(My Magit version is v3.3.0)

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to do it in **one line command** with bash script as below:

`$ cd /path/to/your/repo && /bin/bash $HOME/remove_submodule.sh /path/to/the/submodule`

Create bash script file in the `$HOME` dir named i.e. `remove_submodule.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

git config -f .gitmodules --remove-section submodule.$1
git config -f .git/config --remove-section submodule.$1
git rm --cached $1
git add .gitmodules
git commit -m "Remove submodule in $1"
rm -rf $1
rm -rf .git/modules/$1
git push origin $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) --force --quiet
```

Answer (score 1):

- A submodule can be deleted by running `git rm <submodule path> && git commit`. This can be undone using `git revert`.

  - The deletion removes the superproject's tracking data, which are both the gitlink entry and the section in the `.gitmodules` file.
  - The submodule's working directory is removed from the file system, but the Git directory is kept around as it to make it possible to checkout past commits without requiring fetching from another repository.
- **To completely remove a submodule, additionally manually delete `$GIT_DIR/modules/<name>/`**.

Source: `git help submodules`

Comment: Good explanation for the fact that git doesn't remove the internal data, so we can see that this is a feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1260982/7915017) I made an [example](https://github.com/AndreiCherniaev/AddsubmoduleRemovesubmoduleAddsubmodule) how to add a submodule, then remove and then add it again.

#### 0) Clone my example repo

Simple way

```
git clone --remote-submodules --recurse-submodules -j8 https://github.com/AndreiCherniaev/AddsubmoduleRemovesubmoduleAddsubmodule.git
cd AddsubmoduleRemovesubmoduleAddsubmodule/
```

Or in several steps

```
git clone  https://github.com/AndreiCherniaev/AddsubmoduleRemovesubmoduleAddsubmodule.git
cd AddsubmoduleRemovesubmoduleAddsubmodule/
git submodule update --remote --merge
```

#### 1) Add Buildroot as submodule

```
$ git submodule add -b master https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot myBuildroot/buildroot
```

#### 2) Remove submodule Buildroot

```
$ git rm -f myBuildroot/buildroot
```

#### 3) Add Buildroot as submodule again

```
$ git submodule add -b master https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot myBuildroot/buildroot
fatal: A git directory for 'myBuildroot/buildroot' is found locally with remote(s):
  origin    https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot
If you want to reuse this local git directory instead of cloning again from
  https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot
use the '--force' option. If the local git directory is not the correct repo
or you are unsure what this means choose another name with the '--name' option.
```

Because I already have folder 'myBuildroot/buildroot' in my computer, you can remove the folder:

```
rm -rf .git/modules/myBuildroot/buildroot
git config --remove-section submodule.myBuildroot/buildroot
```

And go to step 1). Another way to do step 3) is to remove the repo from your computer and clone again from Github, then you can do step 1). Tested with git version 2.34.1

Answer (score 0):

In latest git just 4 operation is needed to remove the git submodule.

- Remove corresponding entry in  `.gitmodules`
- Stage changes `git add .gitmodules`
- Remove the submodule directory `git rm --cached <path_to_submodule>`
- Commit it `git commit -m "Removed submodule xxx"`

Answer (score 0):

## Removing git submodule

To remove a `git` submodule below 4 steps are needed.

1. Remove the corresponding entry in  `.gitmodules` file. Entry might be like mentioned below

```
[submodule "path_to_submodule"]
    path = path_to_submodule
    url = url_path_to_submodule
```

2. Stage changes `git add .gitmodules`
3. Remove the submodule directory `git rm --cached <path_to_submodule>`.
4. Commit it `git commit -m "Removed submodule xxx"` and push.

Additional 2 more steps mentioned below are needed to clean submodule completely in local cloned copy.

5. Remove the corresponding entry in `.git/config` file. Entry might be like mentioned below

```
[submodule "path_to_submodule"]
    url = url_path_to_submodule
```

6. Do `rm -rf .git/modules/path_to_submodule`

These 5th and 6th steps does not creates any changes which needs commit.

Comment: It would be much easier if you would use `git submodule deinit` 
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-deinit-f--force--all--ltpathgt82308203

Answer (score -2):

Because most things in github never go the way the commands tell you you should, you might have to go into the directory that can't be added and delete the .git folder and all it's contents with a command line like:

```
rm -fr .git*
```

and then try adding the folder again

```
git add folder/
```

That MIGHT work but with the poorly designed github commands it's a crap shoot...