# git status shows nothing even though i made changes

Tags: git

So it appears this seems to happen when I'm about to get a merge conflict, so before I do anything I wanted to ask.

I'm working in my own branch, so idk why there would be a merge conflict, and not even sure if that has anything to do with my problem.

I made a bunch of changes, and when I go into cmd, I type `git status` and nothing appears, even though in my github desktop application I indeed see the changes I made.

I could obviously just work out of the desktop application, but this is incredibly annoying and I have no idea why it's happening.

[image]

So as shown in my screenshot. My github desktop application shows the appropriate changes, where the cmd shows nothing when i type `git status`. I've tried some things that I found in other posts like this, as you can see from screenshot (`git status -v` and `git diff`) but nothing seemed to really work.

What am I doing wrong? And how can I fix?

**EDIT**

Someone thought that perhaps I don't have git installed correctly, so I just wanted to clarify something. Git is installed fine. I didn't really mention this in my question, so I think it's fair that someone thought that. But I can *usually* do `git status` and it works fine, it's just happens seemingly randomly (perhaps I'm doing something to trigger it? No idea) that `git status` shows nothing in cmd but shows fine in github application.

Comment: sorry, maybe not relevant but you can try with git bash. Also, are your sure you're in the right directory ?

Comment: Are you sure that path on disk is the same workspace that your GUI tool is looking at?

Comment: @JazZ Tbh I did not include it in my post that it works most of the time, and almost randomly does what I described. I see why you may have thought I didn't have git installed properly. I updated my question to include this information, thanks.

Comment: @Mort See my update, yes I am sure. Most of the time I do this and it shows the changes, what seemingly is random to me is that sometimes it shows nothing. Not the end of the world seeing as I can just do it in the github application, I just am very curious as to why this is happening and if it's something I'm doing to make it happen

Comment: My bad, I could see that git commands return no error.

Comment: Is there a .gitignore file ? Maybe a cache or index problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993082/why-doesnt-git-recognize-that-my-file-has-been-changed-therefore-git-add-not-w

Comment: I do have a git ignore, the only thing in is it `.DS_Store` so I don't think that's it. I will look into possibly if it's a caching or index problem, thanks for the link!

Comment: Just though about that, you said you're working on a different branch, right ? Did you checked out to that branch from the command line ? (it seems obvious but you know sometimes…) Good Luck !

Comment: @JazZ Yeah I just double checked and I'm indeed on the same branch =\

Comment: What's the response of the command `git ls-files -v` ? See the [Nate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329361/why-is-git-ignoring-my-changed-file) for more details.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem :(.  I use git bash (windows) and sometimes git status works correctly, and other times it returns literally nothing (no text whatsoever).  I suspect it may be an auth problem, but I don't know how to get any debug output from git status.

Comment: i think it has to with using cmd line instead of git bash. i dont have the issue in git bash/github client.