# How to make top-level git to track all the files under another sub-directory git

Tags: git, git-submodules

### command sequence

> mkdir topdir
>   mkdir another-git-directory
>   touch fileC
>   touch fileD
>   git add .
>   git commit -m "sub-dir init"
>   cd ..
>   touch fileA
>   touch fileB
>   git add .
>   git commit -m "top-dir init"
>   git ls-files
>   // now we can see that fileC and fileD is not tracked by top-level git //
>   git ls-files -o
>   // this would not show us the fileC and fileD as untracked files//

my question is: how can we make "git ls-files -o" to show the untracked files inside sub-directory? why git is behaved such, as i expect git ls-files to show all untracked file (even it is inside another sub-dir git)?

I know that I could make the top git to track the sub-dir files using "git add */."... but I am interested to know why for the question above. Thanks!

directory structure

> ```
>  topdir +  
>         +-- .git  
>         +-- fileA  
>         +-- fileB  
>         + another-git-directory +-- .git  
>                                 +-- fileC  
>                                 +-- fileD
> ```

### update (26 Jun)

I found this thread [Unable to track files within Git submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084969/unable-to-track-files-in-deep-directories-by-git) and this url (cn) http://blog.ossxp.com/2010/01/425/ which explains how to resolve the problem.

the solution:

> git rm --cached another-git-directory   #no trailing slash
>   git add another-git-directory/.
>   git commit

the 'git rm --cached path/to/sub-dir-or-sub-module' will tell the top-dir not to treat the sub-dir as a submodule... I think....

Answer (score 2):

A nested repo is by default <del>untracked</del>.
(actually it tracks the submodule root folder as a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309))
Git will detect the nested `.git` repo, and the parent repo will delegate any file status to the nested one.

To show them tracked, you may have to:

- remove the gitlink: `git rm --cached mysubmodule`.
  Note the lack of trailing slash: `mysubmodule` represents the gitlink, while `mysubmodule/` is the folder created by the checked out submodule.
- add it back to the index of the parent repo: `git add mysubmodule` (here, you can add or not a trailing slash, it does not matter)
- commit the new files added and present in `mysubmodule`.

Comment: Thanks Vonc. There is constraints as the sub-dir git is not created by me so first approach is out. For the submodule, as I read from your link, it doesn't seems to do what I want, as I want to generate the diff for files in all sub-dir(s) from the top-dir. I have updated git 1.7.1 and try "git status -u all" but still it doesn't show the untracked fileC and fileD

Comment: @insidepower: strange, that notion should be available: just clone that nested repo elsewhere, then delete it, and recreate it as a submodule. Then the git status will show any modification for C and D (only if you modify them of course)

Comment: okay, i set the submodulesummary to true using "git config status.submodulesummary true" and it now spit out the submodules changes. but it does not tell which files have changes, just the summary of it. 

e.g. modified:   sub-dir2 (modified content)

btw, the 'git status' in 1.7.1 is very very very slow on large project. I am going to change back.... sigh

Comment: @insidepower: strange (bis) Are you using a msysgit Windows distribution for git? Note: You can also try `git config status.showUntrackedFiles no` to only stat files in your index. If you need to show untracked files at some point, you can always do: `git status -unormal`

Comment: @VonC: no I am using ubuntu, current built is 1.6.0.4 if i didn't remember wrongly. I have switched back to this version and the git status is back to normal rate. Sigh now I couldn't try the showUntrackedFiles option unless I switch back to 1.7.1 again. However I don't think I can tolerate the speed of its 'git status'... This is Life I guess :)

Comment: @insidepower: I agree, `git status` is very slow from 1.7+: see http://longair.net/blog/2010/06/02/git-submodules-explained/ and http://lists-archives.org/git/719848-git-status-and-git-diff-now-very-slow-in-project-with-a-submodule.html