# Symfony vendors in git project

Tags: github, symfony-2.1, vendor

I have a Symfony project, which was always held in an svn project.
Now I am trying to make the move to git (on github).

The problem is that

```
git status
```

always tells me that there are modified and new files/folders, which I cannot seem to commit...

When I

```
git add
```

these files/folders, then commit will just tell me I have nothing to commit, and that the files/folders are still untracked?

All the other stuff in my Symfony project is committed and pushed file, its just certain stuff in the vendors folder which I can't seem to get going.

How can I fix this?

ps: I am also having trouble getting composer to update my vendors.

Comment: Did you tried '`git add .`' instead of just '`git add`'?

Comment: i have tried 'git add .'             'git add ./'      'git add [fileOrFolderInQuestion]',     nothing, i guess it has to do with the fact that the vendors also have .git folders inside of them ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best practice is to completely ignore the `vendors` directory, and install all the vendors bundle with [composer](http://getcomposer.org) on every development machine using `composer.json` and `composer.lock` (thus, you will need to add these files to your repo!)

Comment: this is the approach we eventually took, i just couldnt at first because the composer was throwing errors, its fixed now and we are running composer manually on each machine .

Answer (score 1):

> i guess it has to do with the fact that the vendors also have .git folders inside of them

I confirm a **nested git repo** won't respond well to git command, if that nested repo already consider said files committed.
Or, at the very least, you should add those files while being within that nested repo (not from a parent directory).

However, a git status done in a parent directory should ignore the content of that nested repo. See [How to make top-level git to track all the files under another sub-directory git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115249/how-to-make-top-level-git-to-track-all-the-files-under-another-sub-directory-git) .