# How to get Vim Ctrl-P plugin to index files inside a git submodule

Tags: git, vim, git-submodules, vim-plugin

If I run Ctrl-P natively out of the box, it works 100% as I desire, except that with the size of the codebase I work with, it takes a very long time to index directories.

To make Ctrl-P cope with the project sizes I'm dealing with, I'm using the following (fairly popular) user_command setting in my .vimrc file to provide native helper-utilities to more quickly provide Ctrl-P with the list of files available:

```
if has("unix")
    let g:ctrlp_user_command = {
    \ 'types': {
        \ 1: ['.git/', 'cd %s && git ls-files']
    \ },
    \ 'fallback': 'find %s -type f | head -' . g:ctrlp_max_files
    \ }
endif
```

This approach makes indexing blazingly fast, but when configured this way Ctrl-P doesn't learn about the contents of git submodules the way that it did when running without helper programs (since 'git ls-files' doesn't recurse into submodules, while Ctrl-P's naive directory traversal does).

I've tried using 'find' to index git repositories as well, but when I do that I wind up indexing .git directories, object files, and all sorts of other things that Ctrl-P normally knows to ignore automatically;  seems like providing a user_command completely supersedes the built-in logic about which files to ignore.  I could probably hack together an inverse grep to remove certain elements, but it seemed like someone must have figured out a more elegant solution to this.

Is there another, perhaps cleverer way to get Ctrl-P to index all files within a git repository, including the files inside all its submodules, other than resorting to its slow built-in search?

Comment: [It looks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115249/how-to-make-top-level-git-to-track-all-the-files-under-another-sub-directory-git) like Git doesn't track files in submodules. You must actively add them for `git ls-files` to show them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use find with options to filter out file you don't want like :

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.cpp" -or -name "*.h" \)
```

or removing .git directories :

```
find . -path '.git' -prune -o -print
```

but this is not a *smart* solution.

Comment: The `-path '.git'` command doesn't work for me, because `find .` provides paths with "./" on the front of them.  Either `find * -path '.git' -prune -o -print` (to exclude a '.git' directory at the top level), or `find . -name '.git' -prune -o -print` (to exclude '.git' files and directories anywhere within the search) will work.  As you say, these aren't really *smart* solutions, but they'll do in a pinch, and the latter is what I'm actually using at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/), which skips VCS dirs like .git, .svn, .hg, etc.

I use ack a lot at work, it's great for global find and replace.  I used find once, piping that into xargs with a perl one liner regex.  Unfortunately, this completely destroyed code in my .git dir.  I was unable to commit my changes, and unable to checkout, reset, or revert at that point.  I had to checkout the codebase anew after that!  Ack is significantly easier to use than find when trying to exclude directories, just use the --ignore-dir flag (or --noignore-dir to search in non default ones).

Comment: I don't think this is really relevant for listing files, but I agree that ack is a fantastic replacement for grep for programmers.  I've recently switched from ack to [the silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) ("ag"), which is even faster still.. and is probably about as fast as a 'grep' tool can get without pre-building an index the way that ctags does.  Worth looking at, if you haven't already done so.

Comment: It is actually quite relevant. You can hook ag into CtrlP pretty easily. No useless files clogging up your matches with ridiculous speeds. Here's my config for it: https://github.com/Wolfy87/vim-config/blob/2d9ede6096fa07144f5ba71ac9dc8b5ed18067e3/bundles.vim#L113-L114

Answer (score 1):

I started using a variation on one of the other answers from this post, but had some performance issues due to all the calls to `echo`.  My index resulted in about 65k files, and using this syntax `git ls-files -co --exclude-standard | while read i; do echo \"\$path/\$i\"; done` took nearly 3 seconds to generate.  Converting to use `sed` saved me all of that time.

```
let g:ctrlp_user_command = {
  \ 'types': {
    \ 1: ['.git', 'cd %s && git ls-files -co --exclude-standard && git submodule foreach "git ls-files -co --exclude-standard | sed \"s#^#\$path/#\""'],
    \ 2: ['.hg', 'hg --cwd %s locate -I .'],
    \ },
  \ 'fallback': 'find %s -type f'
  \ }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use git-submodule-foreach to descend in submodules and run `ls-files` there (adding the submodule path to those file names):

```
let g:ctrlp_user_command = ['.git', 'cd %s && git ls-files -co --exclude-standard && git submodule foreach "git ls-files -co --exclude-standard | while read i; do echo \"\$path/\$i\"; done"']
```