# How do I add files in Git to the path of a former submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a project that used to contain a submodule, at path `mysubmodule`.  I installed the latest Git from source (1.8.3-rc2) and ran `git submodule deinit mysubmodule`.  I then deleted the `.gitmodules` file and committed the change.  I also deleted the `.git` directory from the `mysubmodule` folder.

I'd like to commit the files from `mysubmodule` into my repo directly now, but git says there are no changes.  If I type `git add mysubmodule` it does nothing.  If I type `git add mysubmodule/file.txt` it says `fatal: Path 'mysubmodule/file.txt' is in submodule 'mysubmodule'`

I've also discovered if you check out a fresh version of the repo, it creates a `mysubmodule` directory, despite having no `.gitmodules` file.  And running `git submodule init` gives you a `No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'mysubmodule'` error.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you checked all of [these steps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1260982/955926) to ensure there are no parts of the submodule lingering around? I don't think `deinit` entirely removes the submodule. It appears to simply remove it from your `.git/config` file, as though you'd cloned a repo with a submodule, but had not yet run `git init`. That's different than entirely removing the submodule. If this is the case, git still thinks that folder is a submodule, but is ignoring it.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Git still think `mysubmodule` is a submodule, because it is recorded in the index with a special mode "160000".
See "[git submodule update needed only initially?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992018/git-submodule-update-needed-only-initially/2227598#2227598)" for more.
To check that, as in [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4010165/6309), you can do a:

```
 $ git ls-tree HEAD mysubmodule 
 160000 commit c0f065504bb0e8cfa2b107e975bb9dc5a34b0398  mysubmodule
```

That doesn't depend on the presence of the `.gitmodule` file, or on the content of `mysubmodule`.

You need to remove that entry from the index first:

```
 git rm --cached mysubmodule
```

Then you can proceed.

Comment: `git ls-tree HEAD mysubmodule` gave me no results but `git ls-files --stage | grep mysubmodule` worked. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992018/git-submodule-update-needed-only-initially/2227598#2227598). Why would that be?

Comment: @nzn Not sure: I just tested both, and they work. What git version are you using, on which OS?